# PHP functions array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an `array()` inside of a function in PHP.

```
$CheckInfo->gatherInfo(array("hej", "ds"), "email");
```

And then collect it as:

```
public function checkSecurity($input, $type){

            // Set new varibels
            $input = htmlentities(addslashes($input));
            $type = htmlentities(addslashes($type));

            $this->findPath($input, $type);

        }
```

But once I do use `htmlentities(addslashes))` if gives me this error:
*Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in*

Without addslashes and htmlentities, it gives me a return on "array". How may I use a array, read it and use it in a function?

Comment: Seems like you are using functions that are used on strings instead of arrays. You can loop over all elements in the array with a `foreach`-loop, and use those functions on each element in the array. If you try to treat an array as a string, it will output  `Array`.

Comment: What `findPath` expects? An array or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map()` function for this. `array_map()` applies the callback function to each element of the array.

```
private function sanitize_elements($element){
    return htmlentities(addslashes($element));
}

public function checkSecurity($input, $type){

    $input = array_map(array($this, 'sanitize_elements'), $input);
    $type = htmlentities(addslashes($type));
    $this->findPath($input, $type);

}
```

So it will send each value of the array to `sanitize_elements()` method, apply `htmlentities()` and `addslashes()` function to each value, and return an array with the new values.

Here's the reference:

- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)